# “The evening is spread out AGAINST the sky”

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

> Let us go then, you and I,
>   When the evening is **spread out against** the sky
>   Like a patient etherized upon a table...

*The Love Song of J. Alfred Prufrock by T. S. Eliot*

What does *against* mean in this context? Why is it used instead of *across*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to "interpret" unusual poetic imagery.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you’re not right. The question is about a) choosing AGAINST instead of usual ACROSS, b) about the special meaning of “spread out AGAINST” which is not clear if the one is not a native speaker. I don’t ask, “What did the author want to say?”

Comment: "Evening" is an abstract noun, which could reasonably be figuratively referenced using spatial imagery *(We had a boring evening that stretched until midnight)*, but it's effectively *meaningless* to consider different possible "meanings" dependent on whether Eliot had chosen to use ***across*** rather than ***against***. Are you seriously suggesting there could be two "different" mental images of abstract / invisible "evening" to choose between here? This isn't about *language* - it's about arresting poetic imagery.

Comment: @FumbleFingers if you replace your thoughts in the answer, I will be thankful. Now you are just trying to close my question without any appropriate reason (that is like I see actions).

Comment: In some *other* context, it might make sense to contrast something spread out *against* some background (alluding to ***contrast***) and something spread *across* that background (alluding to ***extent***). But that's totally irrelevant in the current context. And it's worth noting that even though Eliot *could* have (equivalently?) used ***across*** for the "evening" image, it would be *really* weird to speak of an etherized patient being spread out *against* a table (but he could certainly be spread out *across* the table).

Comment: @FumbleFingers you ask yourself a question about the equivalence, so do I. Sorry, but I see no sense in this comment discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A patient is spread out on a table. That could be the case of patient waiting to undergo surgery. Spread out here is extended on the table.

**So the evening is to the sky**

**as the patient is to the table.**

The patient does not take up all the space on the table. Just like the evening does not take up (fill up) the whole sky.

Against means the evening is not taking up the whole sky. It's like a picture on a wall. Or **any object against any background.** The evening is, in effect, viewed against the backdrop of the sky. Just like the table is the background for the patient if you were viewing the  patient on a table from above.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

> The silhouette of the trees stood out starkly **against** the evening sky.

or this:

> Those faces in the crowd were like petals **against** a wet black bough.

The meaning is of "contrast" and "juxtaposition".

Do you see the Latinate underpinnings of the word "contrast"?

Now, to ask us to explain how **evening** can occupy the slot occupied by "silhouette" and "petals", that would be to get into literary interpretation, which is off-topic for this site.